# How to Linq DbContext with Array or list having flexible length

Tags: c#, linq

How to Linq DbContext with Array or list having flexible length.

I have one int array or list, for example { 4, 6, 12, 24, 32 }, it means days. I have one table with million records, it has one DateTime field `LastProcessDate` and one int field `Counter`.

The query condition is If Counter = 0 , LastProcessDate + 4 days < DateTime.UtcNow, or If Counter = 1 , LastProcessDate + 6 days < DateTime.UtcNow, or … so on.

I searched on internet, array and datetime can not be used in Linq. So I wrote following code.

```
int counter0= myArray[0];
int counter1= myArray[1];
int counter2= myArray[2];.....
var records = myDbcontext.myTable
    .where( (m => m.Counter == counter0 && DateTime.UtcNow > DbFunctions.AddDays(x.LastProcessDate, counter0)) || (m=>m.Counter == counter1 && DateTime.UtcNow > DbFunctions.AddDays(x.LastProcessDate, counter1)) …… )
    .where(...other condition….).
```

The problem is that array or list are entered by users, the length is not fixed. One way is to query everything and filter them in C#, it will have performance issue. Another way is set big length of array or list.

How can I write the Linq without big performance issue? Thanks

Comment: Please don't use linq for huge data. Stick with foreach or for loops please

Comment: Normally, it will return less than 100 records, it will search data to check if the records are processed, thanks

Comment: Entity Framework should made developers life easy. In case you are struggling - write raw SQL query. So you will get application working. Then you, for example, can specified computed column in database, which will calculate date for comparing. Then your query will look like `Where(m => m.CalculatedDate < DateTime.UtcNow)`

Comment: Thanks, Fabio. But if user decided to enter different days to array, CalculatedData only shows old logic, not new one. It can not get correct records with new array.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with AsExpandable() method from  LinqKit and Expressions.

LinqKit is available as nuget [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqKit/) and you can read more in it [here](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx).

```
myDbcontext.myTable.AsExpandable()
                  .Where(m=> array.Any(
                  x=>Evaluate.Invoke(m.Counter,m.LastProcessedDate,x)));
```

Where Evaluate is defined as

```
Expression<Func<int,DateTime,int,bool> Evaluate = (counter,lastProcessedDate,counterFromArray) =>
                 counter > counterFromArray 
                 && DateTime.UtcNow > DbFunctions.AddHours(lastProcessedHoursDate,counterFromArray);
```

AsExpandable is a thin wrapper around DLINQ Table object which allows you to use custom methods while still being able to translate to Sql.

You can read more on AsExpandable and writing methods in Linq Queries in post by Tomas Petricek,  [here](http://tomasp.net/blog/linq-expand.aspx/)

Comment: Thanks, are you sure that myArray.Any will work in LINQ? What I remembered that I can not write array in LINQ, that is why I have trouble.

Comment: @q.x I have updated my answer. Kindly check. And Any() worked.